# If "text" then, how to put a conditional formula

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-arrayformula

There are three columns. A, B and results.
I need to make a formula that gives the following:

If the text in both columns A and B is WIN, then in the results we should see: Winner.
If the text in column A is WIN and in B is LOSE, then in results we should see: Try again
If the Text in both columns A and B is LOSE, then in results we should see: Loser.

Comment: Welcome. Please remember that as per [site guidelines](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) when an answer addresses your question, you should [accept](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it so others can benefit as well.

Answer (score 1):

The formula you need is:

```
=IFERROR(ArrayFormula(
     IF((M13:M16="WIN")(N13:N16="WIN"),"Winner",
     IF((M13:M16="WIN")(N13:N16="LOSE"),"Try again",
     IF((M13:M16="LOSE")*(N13:N16="LOSE"),"Loser","")))))
```

[image]

Please adjust columns and cell numbers to your needs